# Java Calculator giving action

Tags: java, netbeans, calculator

I would like to know how can I make the numbers to stay at the textfield of my calculator instead of disappear like when I type 1 then hit the + sign the number 1 disappears from the textfield. I would like to have this (1+1) showing in the text field and also if try to press only + , * , - , / to show error. My if else statements won't work.

I'm using netbeans I'm start to learn how to program I would like to have some more ideas about programming and some good books.

This is part of my code it is working but not the way that I want to.

```
private void jbtNum1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    display = jtfResult.getText();
    jtfResult.setText(display + "1");
}                                       

private void jbtNum2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    display = jtfResult.getText();
    jtfResult.setText(display + "2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your jtfResult is a JTextArea. I believe that you can use /n to create a new line. If you are using JTextField, that is for single lines only and you need to switch to JTextArea.+

```
private void jbtNum1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)         {                                        

               display = jtfResult.getText();
               jtfResult.setText(display + "1" + "/n"); // <------- Here
}                                       

private void jbtNum2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    display = jtfResult.getText();
    jtfResult.setText(display + "2" + "/n"); // <------- Here

}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it won't work,, when i press 1 then the + the number 1 disappear from the textfiel, i would like to have 1+1 showing there

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know what you are talking about now. Use jtfResult.append(String). Append adds a new String at the end of another String that is already in the TextField.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you give me an example ? but it's starts to make sense now